# Convert Multiple Array Into XML In PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml

i have two array, here's the first:

```
Array
(
    [0] => BWY DL
    [1] => SP_GPON
)
//Array 1
```

This is the last one:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Two Way
        [1] => Ultimated
    )
//Array 2
```

Both of them will be convert into XML. Format that I want:

```
<data>
   <citem>BWY DL</citem> //from array 1, array[0]
   <desc>Two Way</desc> //from array 2, array[0]
</data>
<data>
   <citem>SP_GPON</citem> //from array 1, array[1]
   <desc>Ultimated</desc> //from array 2, array[1]
</data>
```

My code for convert:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<data/>');
    array_walk_recursive($value, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
    array_walk_recursive($desc, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
    $output=$xml->asXML();

print_r($output);
```

But it gave:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <BWY DL>0</BWY DL>
  <Two Way>0</Two Way>
  <SP_GPON>1</SP_GPON>
  <Ultimated>1</Ultimated>
</data>
```

I don't know how to set them into the format. Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Do the arrays ever contain sub arrays?

Comment: no, there's no sub arrays @JasonMcCreary

Comment: Then there's no need to use recursive. I'd just use a simple `for` loop to build the XML. No reason to be *fancy*.

Comment: Could you explain it on code? I don't know how to do it @JasonMcCreary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it suits your requirement.
Giving that your arrays are fixed length and the format is always the same:

```
function convert($array) {
    $format = "<data><citem>%s</citem><desc>%s</desc></data>";
    return sprintf($format, $array[0], $array[1]);
}
```

so if you have arrays like these: `$array1 = array("citem1", "desc1");` `$array2 = array("citem2", "desc2");`

```
echo convert($array1); // <data><citem>citem1</citem><desc>desc1</desc></data>
echo convert($array2); // <data><citem>citem2</citem><desc>desc2</desc></data>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: ok thanks @SarenArterius but how convert it into xml? thank u

Comment: The output of convert($array) itself is a xml string. You can copy the string to a xml file/string or to create a new xml file/string from the string the function returned.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that doesn't focus on combining the arrays or leverage native array functions would be a `for` loop.

```
$xml = '';
$format = '<data><citem>%s</citem><desc>%s</desc></data>';
$count = count($array1);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $xml = sprintf($format, $array1[$i], $array2[$i]);
}

echo $xml;
```

**Note:** this assumes the arrays are of the same length.